# Functioning of ModelAndView class in spring mvc 3

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

This may sound really stupid but I am unable to understand the flow of **Spring MVC** in my project.

When I write the below mentioned code, what happens?

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("paging");
```

I have a `paging.jsp` in my project but what happens, how does it flow?

Answer (score 1):

When you write in your method

```
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("paging");
    ...
    return mav;
```

you tell Spring that you return model and view with the name *paging*.  In configuration you need to tell Spring how to resolve this name. In your case you could use `UrlBasedViewResolver`:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

For more information check Spring [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html): *Resolving Views*